# Codeigniter Database error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i want create a account to test if insert into to the DB works I get this error

> Error Number: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 0 = 'test' LIMIT 1' at line 2

```
SELECT * WHERE 0 = 'test' LIMIT 1
```

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/stg/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

My controler code Main.php:

```
$data = array();
$userData = array();
if($this->input->post('insert')){           

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 
                                      'username', 
                                'trim|required|is_unique|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 
                                      'password',
               'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]|callback_is_password_strong');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 
                                      'confirm password', 
                                      'required|matches[password]');

    $userData = array(
       'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
       'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );

    if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
        $insert = $this->login_model->insert($userData);
        if($insert){
            $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg', 
                     'Your registration was successfully. Please login to your account.');
            redirect('login');
        }else{
            $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
        }
    }
}
$data['user'] = $userData;
//load the view
$this->load->view('register', $data);
}
```

My model code Login_model.php:

```
public function insert($data = array()){
    //add created and modified data if not included
    if(!array_key_exists("created", $data)){
        $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
    if(!array_key_exists("modified", $data)){
        $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}

$insert = $this->db->insert('login' ,$data);

if($insert){
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}else{
    return false;
}
echo $insert;
}
```

Comment: what version of codeigniter?

Comment: 3.1.5 newest version.

Comment: I just click submit button to insert user to the DB but i get this error.

Comment: According to me this data should to the login table but missing somebody

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)This error come because you used `is_unique` in below Line

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|is_unique|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
```

So Syntax is wrong , if you using `is_unique` then

```
is_unique[table.field]
```

where table -> replace with your user table where you storing username
      field -> replace with name of the column in which username are stored

background of `is_unique` is

```
select * from table_name where fields_name= your_varaible_value
```

so you didn't mention table name as well as field name that's why in this query table name is missing

```
SELECT * WHERE 0 = 'test' LIMIT 1 // here table name is not present so Error Number: 1064  is occurred.
```